# Codeigniter Controller setup

Tags: codeigniter

I am trying to build an application that can search the database for different City information. (for example: if the user click New York, it will show lots of information about New York.) Do I have to create different controllers for different cities? like New York controller -> New York Model. Seattle controller -> Seattle Model. Chicago controller -> Chicago Model That sounds redundant. What is the best way to approach my problem. Thanks for the helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a City model with a lookup function that accepts a city name as a parameter and returns whatever relevant data.  Then, you'll have a controller that accepts a city as a parameter, too.  So, for example, http://localhost/index.php/city/lookup/new_york where city is the controller, lookup is the function, and new_york is the parameter to the function.

The lookup function in the controller would pass the parameter it received to the city model lookup function.  Whatever the model returns, the controller would pass to the view to be rendered.

You should probably *not* have a separate controller and model for each city.

Comment: Thanks. I thought about your way before I posted, just wasn't sure if this is the best practice. Now I know i can do it now. Thanks.